# images disappeared after creating subdomain

Tags: magento-1.9, frontend

Working on magento 1.9 store after getting a improvement suggestion from gtmetrix to serve content from cookieless domain.

( suppose domain is www.example.com )

i created a subdomain cdn.example.com and directed to www.example.com and on magento  **Unsecure Url's** did following

Base Link URL           http://www.example.com/

Base Skin URL           http://cdn.example.com/skin/

Base Media URL          http://cdn.example.com/media/

Base JavaScript URL     http://cdn.example.com/js/

**Secure Url's**

Base Link URL           https://www.example.com/

Base Skin URL           https://cdn.example.com/skin/

Base Media URL          https://cdn.example.com/media/

Base JavaScript URL     https://cdn.example.com/js/

on website product images and logo are showing properly but some other images such as cart logo, social sharing logo's are not showing properly here with i attach the images after and before change of url.

before changing url :
[image]
after changing url :
[image]

how can this be resolved ?

Comment: Have you changed this configurations from admin:
`Base Skin URL - {{secure_base_url}}skin/` 
`Base Media URL - {{secure_base_url}}media/`
`Base Javascript URL - {{secure_base_url}}js/`

Comment: yes, i changed the same

Comment: Have you checked same for store view AND website? Can you share URL?

Comment: yes, website is www.i-ranu.com

Comment: I have tried it with adding `cdn.`, and  it is woking for me

Comment: sir, apologies earlier i haven't changes the settings now please check again issue is showing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` for your CDN URL. Your Font files are not loading that's why social logos not displaying.

Here is the Error:

```
Access to Font at 'http://cdn.i-ranu.com/skin/frontend/smartwave/porto/icons/font/porto.woff2?20988115' from origin 'http://www.i-ranu.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://www.i-ranu.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Comment: Welcome, happy to help you!!!